# Installing software in kubuntu

Tags: linux, apt, apt-get, ubuntu

I have recently installed kubuntu. I am able to install softwares from muon software center. But when I try to do so from the terminal, I get errors. For instance on trying to update, I get:

```
Err http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease

Err http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg 
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease      

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg    
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Similarly when I try to install git-core, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-arch git-cvs git-svn
  git-email git-gui gitk gitweb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-core git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,704 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main liberror-perl all 0.17-1
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.92.202). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main git-man all 1:1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main git i386 1:1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main git-core all 1:1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17-1_all.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.92.202). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git-man_1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git-core_1.7.10.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How do I handle this. I am using internet behind a proxy server, if that matters.

Comment: Your question belongs more to superuser than to stackoverflow.

Comment: Or askubuntu, preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your proxy config to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy-ip-or-hostname:port";
```

eg:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.0.1:3128";
```

or with authentication

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@192.168.0.1:3128";
```

Comment: I have always had this problem. This seems to be a permanent solution. Thanks!